# Decimal binary sequences that cannot be greater than $1$

Tags: number-theory, binary-operations

Consider the family of sequences of the form $.012\ldots n$ for any natural number $n$. So, the sequences in this family are: $.01, .012, .0123, .01234,$ etc.

Now consider to manipulate each sequence in this way:

1) Start from the rightmost digit; let's say that the rightmost digit is $n$;
2) If $n$ is even, replace $n$ by $0$ and add $n/2$ to the digit immediately on the left;
3) if $n$ is odd, replace $n$ by $1$ and add $(n-1)/2$ to the digit immediately on the left;
4) keep on modifying the sequence on the left until the only digits are '$0$' and '$1$'.

E.g., suppose that you consider the sequence $.01234.$ Then you modify it in this way: $.01250; .01410; .03010; .11010$.

I want to show that, for any $n$, after rewriting the sequence with only '$0$' and '$1$', I will never obtain any sequence that starts in this way $x.yy$'$y$'... where $x\neq 0$. So, e.g., I will never obtain any sequence like $1.0101$.

This problem is probably analogous to show that any sequence of the form $(0*2^{-1})+(1*2^{-2})+(2*2^{-3})+...+(n*2^{-(n+1)})$ is $<1$. However, I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: When numbers go over 9,we need slightly more careful formulation. I will give an example. Start from .0123456789. So you get: .01234567(12)1; .0123456(13)01; .012345(12)101; .01234(11)0101; .01234910101; etc. So we can imagine that sequences are actually of this form .(x)(y)(z)... The use of parenthesis is unnecessary when numbers are of one digit only.

Comment: Also asked at http://mathoverflow.net/q/182056/12357

Comment: So, for example, it's $$.(0)(1)(2)\cdots(98)(99)\ \to \ .(0)(1)(2)\cdots(98+98/2)(1)$$
and not 
$$.012\cdots9899 \ \to \ .012\cdots98(9+ 8/2)1\ ??$$

Comment: Yes. The second sequence should be disambiguate as follows: .(0)(1)...(9)(8)(9)(9). But here I want to consider only sequence of the form .(0)(1)...(n-1)(n)(n+1)...

Comment: It is true I also asked MO. I am sorry. I did not know this is annoying to someone. I understand it now.The question received an answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/182056/decimal-binary-sequences-that-cannot-be-greater-than-1